# How to simulate a click and drag operation on an ipad?

Tags: javascript, ipad

so this is the setup - An iframe inside a page.

the iframe holds a HTML5 canvas object, which responds to click (hold) and drag...

How do I get this working on an iPad?

I've considering creating event handlers (ontouchstart, ontouchmove, ontouchend), but that didn't seem to work...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow touch interaction, that's the way to do it. Read [Handling Multi-Touch Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) in the Safari Web Content Guide.

Answer (score 0):

There's jQuery plugin that helps you handle drag event in mobile devices. You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-touch-area/).